# Why does this selector for animating font-size of SVG work inconsistently?

Tags: css, svg, css-selectors

My CSS selector seems to work inconsistently when it's applied to SVG. I'm trying to animate an SVG to appear and disappear, but the animation only works for opacity, not font-size.

```
<svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" 
viewBox="0 0 448 512" class="flashCue" height="1em" width="1em" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="left: 10px;"><path d="M257.5 
445.1l-22.2 22.2c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0L7 273c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0- 
33.9L201.4 44.7c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l22.2 22.2c9.5 9.5 9.3 25-.4 
34.3L136.6 216H424c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24v32c0 13.3-10.7 24-24 
24H136.6l120.5 114.8c9.8 9.3 10 24.8.4 34.3z"></path></svg>
```

---

```
.flashCue {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: flash 4s linear;
}
@keyframes flash {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.7;
    font-size: 40px;
  }
}
```

Corresponding JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zfura5h0/1/).

The problem must be with the selector, because replacing `.flashCue` with `*` fixes it.

However, the selector seems to work inconsistently, because I can use the same selector to apply font-size without animation:

```
.flashCue {
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

Why does the selector work in the second code snippet but fail in the first code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

It's not that the class isn't being referenced consistently. **The issue is what you're trying to animate.**

Since there isn't any text in the SVG, any `font-size` setting is going to apply as a basis for your height/width of 1em. I believe this is calculated when the SVG is painted. So animating font-size doesn't cause a repaint. `opacity` Is global to the element so you CAN animate that.

If the goal is to scale the path (arrow) you should animate either height/width or use a `transform: scale();` Both worked for me.

```
@keyframes flash {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.7;
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, transforming with scale works for me too. Although I still don't understand why I can _can_ animate font-size with the `*` selector.

Comment: `*` is a wild card it selects everything in the page, in this case we only have the `body` and an `svg`, and so the animation is applied to the body which will scale the width/height of the svg because of the `em` unit and thus giving the illusion that it is animating the `svg` [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhz8brj4/)